# How do I do an inverted ledge takedown?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

To earn one of the medals in *Batman: Arkham City's* **Police Brutality (Extreme) Predator Challenge**, I'm supposed to do an inverted ledge takedown. I've tried standing on ledges above enemies, but never get the takedown notification. What am I doing wrong? **How do I perform an inverted ledge takedown?**

I'm playing as Batman.

Comment: I believe you can only do this while on a balcony or in a doorway.

Comment: @Ullallulloo I'm playing as Batman. I've edited my question to include that detail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *Inverted Ledge Takedown* requires you to stand on a ledge such as a guardrail. Once you have an enemy approaching below you, and you're given the Takedown prompt, wait a few seconds for the enemy to be facing the opposite direction. (i.e.: If you're facing away from the wall, wait until your target is facing the wall) This [YouTube video](http://youtu.be/vP13rE62v_0?t=30s) posted in another answer shows exactly how it's done (It should start just a few seconds before the takedown). Basically, the bat is facing the opposite direction of the target when he performs the takedown.

Here's a picture showing the actual takedown (to avoid link rot):
[image]

By default:

- **PC** - Right Click
- **Xbox 360** - Y
- **PS3** - Triangle

I played on the Xbox 360, so I'm not 100% on the controls for the PC. If someone makes a correction in the comments, I will edit it into the answer to correct the controls.

Comment: This is an Inverted Takedown. I need to do an Inverted *Ledge* Takedown.

Comment: @splatteredbits Sorry. I was confused. I amended the answer to correct the error.

Answer (score 3):

This one is a pain in the neck.  I seem to remember doing this on the "Gotham PD" level, which has been frozen over by Mr. Freeze.

The strategy I used was to knock everyone out except for the guy wearing the scrambler backpack (since taking him out last is one of the other challenges).  Then, throw a sonic batarang into one of the two large side rooms that have railings over the doorways.

After he heads into the room, stand on the railing above the open doorway.  When the thug is finished investigating the batarang and heads back out towards the center area, you can do the inverted ledge takedown on him.

This guy doesn't use my strategy (although he manages to do it quite a bit quicker) but you can watch him get the takedown here:

Answer (score 0):

You can only do an inverted ledge takedown while standing on on a gargoyle statue. When an enemy walks below you, press the counter button (Trinagle on PS, Y on XBox) to do the takedown.

Comment: You're describing an Inverted Takedown. I need to do an Inverted *Ledge* Takedown.

Comment: Fixed (after thinking I was wrong, editing and then editing back...)